# launching native SMS App from Android notification bar

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to launch native SMS(messaging) App from a notification (which has a button/action to Reply-with-SMS).
With the following code, though the native messaging App gets launched, **but behind the Notification Drawer**. However, I need it to appear in Foreground.

Please suggest.
(Note: if I use ACTION_DIAL, the native Dialer appears directy)

Here is the snippet:

```
 Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 smsIntent.putExtra("address", "123456789");
 smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
 smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:" + "123456789");
 smsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23 && context.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
     context.startActivity(smsIntent);
```